# Excel Pivot Table Cumulative Change

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Basically, I have a set of data, with the following columns: date, price, daily price change and % change, the former two calculated using pivot table field list menu. I want to calculate the cumulative daily change over the period of time, in a next column. As it is a pivot table, it has absolute references and I cannot simply add previous day's change to a today's change one by one, due to a large data set. What is the most efficient way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to pivot table option tab which appears when you select any cell in the pivot table range. The click on the drop down menu **Option** and deselect **Generate GetPivotData**.

[image]

After this, you can use the formulas as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can  add additional column in the main sheet as "cumulative change". The new  column can have the cumulative value and you can use summation formula for this.
Then you can take this value in pivot table for further analysis.
Take the help of Vlookup also. 
You can follow the steps in the video below for detail pivot analysis as per your need.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzd7RUGloXM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsCxOmsMq6k